# Resolving static method at compile-time

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods

It's a common fact that Java compiler (almost) always resolves static methods at compile time. For example:

```
public class Super {
    static void someMethod() {
        // Do something...
    }
}
public class Derived extends Super {
    // Some other methods, excluding someMethod
}
```

Test code:

```
Derived derived = new Derived();
derived.someMethod();
```

This should call Super.someMethod(), right? And it should be resolved at compile-time, so that javac would generate `invokestatic Super.someMethod`, but I've seen that it generates `invokestatic Derived.someMethod`. Why is it doing so? And is there a way to somehow change this behavior?

Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: The javac compiler resolves *all* method references at compile time, in terms of finding the method and checking its signature.  However, the actual "binding" to the method is done when the class is loaded by the JVM or on first call.

Comment: (Why do you want to change the behavior?  It is very useful the way it works.)

Comment: Your code won't even compile. How do you get that byte code?

Comment: I have edited the code to reflect my interpretation of the OP's intention. It doesn't really make sense to call a class "Derived" if it does not actually derive from anything. @kabbi, please post code that can be compiled to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: It should be noted that calling a static method using an instance is a javac "swizzle" that is not really related to how Java works but purely a "convenience".  Coding `SomeClass someRef = new SomeClass(); someRef.someStaticMethod();` is exactly equivalent to coding `SomeClass.someStaticMethod();`.  This has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: @HotLicks I know that. I'm sorry for bad example. Actually this situation happened in ByteBuffer class in the java library. And it was a bit another situation, where `someMethod()` was called from some another method in Derived.
And I understand now, thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume that there's an intermediate superclass between `Super` and `Derived` (called, say, `Intermediate`).

The reason the compiler generates `Derived.someMethod` is that you might recompile `Intermediate` to insert an implementation of `someMethod`, which would shadow the implementation from `Super`.

Comment: Or you might simply edit and recompile Derived to add the method.

Comment: @HotLicks That doesn't address why it generates `Derived.someMethod` a priori.

Comment: The reason why it generates that is that javac never assumes that the situation that exists at compile time is the one that will exist at run time.  Any class outside of the current class can change, and generating invokesuper would cause noncompliant behavior in the face of such a change.

Comment: @HotLicks That is what my answer says, in concrete terms.

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing out that there are other scenarios besides the one you stated where this concept applies.

Answer (score 1):

For the record:

```
public class TestSuperDerived {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        DerivedClass.someMethod();
    }
}
class SuperClass {
    static void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Here!");
    }
}
class DerivedClass extends SuperClass {
    // Some other methods, excluding someMethod
}
```

javap output:

```
C:\JavaTools>javap -c TestSuperDerived
Compiled from "TestSuperDerived.java"
public class TestSuperDerived {
  public TestSuperDerived();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method DerivedClass.someMethod:()V
       3: return
}
```